# If a web application authenticates an user from another domain does it mean it can use LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

As the title says, if the IIS web server running on active directory domain 'domain_A' can authenticate an user (windows authentication) from a domain 'domain_B' does it mean that 'domain_A' can use LDAP to query 'domain_B' ?

As an additional note, I pinged the 'domain_B' ldap on port 389 and it doesn't aswer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not the only approach that would yield the same results. The server in domain_A *could* have something like

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://domaincontroller.domain_B.gTLD/DC=domain_B,DC=gTLD" />
```

to perform authentication against domain_B using LDAP. The connectivity would be from the server in domain_A, so unless you're sourcing the connection attempt from that server ... port 389 (clear text ldap) or 636 (ssl ldap) being closed is not indicative of anything.

But it's also possible the two domains are part of the same forest or a trust has been established between the domains. The web servers could be set up to use basic authentication. You'd need to look at the IIS config on the server in domain_A to be certain.